# JSF: NoSuchMethodException - If I use an interface-type as parameter

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, nosuchmethoderror

I am using a Button in JSF with Primefaces. I made a bean (SearchActions) that have two methods. Both of them have a parameter with an interface-type (IOrder). 
The class Order (which is delivered through the methods) implemets the IOrder-interface.

This is the error I get at viewing the page:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   ....SearchActions.hasOrderStatus(....jpa.model.Order,
>   java.lang.String)

This is my button (the method in the "actionListener" works fine, but the method in the "disabled" does not)

```
<p:commandButton value="Reopen" actionListener="#{searchActions.setOrderStatus(order, 'open')}" disabled="#{!searchActions.hasOrderStatus(order, 'open')}" ajax="false" />
```

These are the two classes that I use:

```
public class Order implements IOrder
{
    ...
}


public class SearchActions
{
    public void setOrderStatus( IOrder order, String statusString ) throws IOException
    {
        ...
    }

    public boolean hasOrderStatus( IOrder order, String statusString ) throws IOException
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

So.. Why does it work with the first method (setOrderStatus) but not with the second method (hasOrderStatus)?

I hope, someone can help me.

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of JSF are you using?

Comment: I am using JSF 2.2.7

Comment: can you post full stack trace? Maybe it is related to some introspector bug

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: ....SearchActions.hasOrderStatus(....jpa.model.Order, java.lang.String)
```

means that 
`order` is not from type `jpa.model.Order`

maybe wrong imports in your bean?

Comment: The object "order" is from the type jpa.model.Order. The problem is, that my methods need a api.model.IOrder type as parameter. jpa.model.Order implements api.model.IOrder. It works the first method, but not with the second method. I don't know, where the differences are.